# Calling JQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, plugins

I'm new to Jquery and have been following some tutorials but this has me stuck. I found a tutorial to make a Jquery clock that works great but I'm trying to convert it to a plugin. The problem I'm having is I have seen how to call a plugin based on a singe div but this has me stumped. Could you have a look at the code for me and show me how I would go about calling the plugin? Thanks

HTML:

```
    <head>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="clock.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Need to call

    </script>

    <style> 
            #clock {
              position: relative;
              width:280px;
              height: 285px;
              margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
              background: url(images/clockface.png);
              list-style: none;
            }

            #sec, #min, #hour {
              position: absolute;
              width: 7px;
              height: 70px;
              top: 125px;
              left: 140px;
            }

            #sec {
              background: url(images/second.png);
              z-index: 3;
            }


            #min {
              background: url(images/min.png);
              z-index: 2;
            }

            #hour {
              background: url(images/hour.png);
              z-index: 1;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="clock"> 
      <li id="sec"></li>
      <li id="hour"></li>
      <li id="min"></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

JS...

```
 (function($){
$.fn.mclock = function(){
    var defaults = {
        var seconds = new Date().getSeconds();
        var sdegree = seconds * 6;
        var hdegree = hours * 30 + (mins / 2);
        },
        options = $.extend(defaults, args);
        console.log(options);

    this.each(function(){
      setInterval( function() {
  var seconds = new Date().getSeconds();
  var sdegree = seconds * 6;
  var srotate = "rotate(" + sdegree + "deg)";

  $("#sec").css({ "transform": srotate });

  }, 1000 );

  setInterval( function() {
  var hours = new Date().getHours();
  var mins = new Date().getMinutes();
  var hdegree = hours * 30 + (mins / 2);
  var hrotate = "rotate(" + hdegree + "deg)";

  $("#hour").css({ "transform": hrotate});

  }, 1000 );

  setInterval( function() {
  var mins = new Date().getMinutes();
  var mdegree = mins * 6;
  var mrotate = "rotate(" + mdegree + "deg)";

  $("#min").css({ "transform" : mrotate });

  }, 1000 );    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: $('#clock').mclock();   ... I can't see the need for any parameters.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want Mark tbh - you seem to say 'how do I call this function' but also say something to do with 'a single div'. What do you want exactly?

Comment: Hi Paul, using that I get the error - Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'mclock' template.html:8
(anonymous function) in console.

Comment: do you make the call after your plugin has loaded? (script order on the page does make a difference)

Comment: Hi Paul, basically the clock just isnt working when I make it a plugin. The hands just don't move. I'm assuming its got something to do with the plugin code in the .js not linking to the code in the HTML correctly as if I don't "turn it into" a plugin then it works fine.

Comment: The clock.js file (where the plugin script is)  loads first (at the top of the page) then I use the code you gave me then I have all the css and HTML

Comment: ahh okay yes you would have to probably (slightly) re-architect the code to fit with plugin - it's been a while since I wrote a jquery plugin so I can't spot the mistake without going back through all the jquery docs). I would start with a fresh plugin, get it working (hello world for example) and then start trying to move the code in

Comment: See answer - I think it breaks as yu aren't returning this.each (which breaks the jquery chain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: Stripping back to hello world revealed missing brace }

NOTE: You aren't return(ing) this.each which might break your plugin

Skeleton plugin

```
/*
 * PLUGIN-NAME
 * PLUGIN-DESCRIPTION
 *
 * Copyright 2011 YOUR-NAME YOUR-WEBSITE-URL
 * Released under the MIT License
 */

(function($){

$.fn.PLUGIN_NAME = function(options) {

    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.PLUGIN_NAME.defaults, options);

    return this.each(function() {

    });

};

$.fn.PLUGIN_NAME.defaults = {
};

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for your help. Your advice to strip it back to get the Hello World Working was great, there must of been some syntax error as I have it all working now :)

Comment: @Mark - was it the missing return? In which case this is the answer - if you still have the missing retrun then this isn't..? :) (and gld to help either way just mark only as answer if the missing return was correct)

Comment: I think it was missing a } somewhere as I made it show just hello world in an alert and it wouldn't still saying there were errors. So I then remade a simple plugin to just alert Hello World which worked fine. I then just reused the other code I had before but with the new basic function and it worked. So yeh seem like there must of been a rouge character or one missing. But thanks for the help if you didn't suggest trying a simple Hello World I wouldn't of fixed it :)